# Dplyr: how to loop over specific columns whose names are in a list?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
set.seed(10)
sample <- data_frame(group = c('A','B','C','C',NA,'D'),
                   var_hello = rnorm(6),
                   var_how = rnorm(6),
                   var_are = rnorm(6),
                   var_you  = rnorm(6),
                   var_buddy = rnorm(6))
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  group   var_hello    var_how     var_are    var_you  var_buddy
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     A  0.01874617 -1.2080762 -0.23823356  0.9255213 -1.2651980
2     B -0.18425254 -0.3636760  0.98744470  0.4829785 -0.3736616
3     C -1.37133055 -1.6266727  0.74139013 -0.5963106 -0.6875554
4     C -0.59916772 -0.2564784  0.08934727 -2.1852868 -0.8721588
5  <NA>  0.29454513  1.1017795 -0.95494386 -0.6748659 -0.1017610
6     D  0.38979430  0.7557815 -0.19515038 -2.1190612 -0.2537805
```

In my original dataset, there are many, many `var_something` variables.

I would like to `group_by('group')` and compute the `mean` of a subset of these `var_something` variables, but even this subset can be large. So I dont want to resort to typing manually each `mutate` for every variable.

In the example, I am interested in variables in the following list `['var_hello', 'var_are']`

I dont know how to code that up efficiently in `dplyr`. In `Pandas`, one could simply write

```
for var in ['var_hello', 'var_are']:
 sample[computation +'_' + var] = sample.groupby('group')[var].agg('mean')
```

Note how I can automatically create the new column names (of the form `computation_var_hello`) . What is the best way to achieve that in `dplyr`?

Many thanks!

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus this is not the case. Here the challenge is to only compute something for a subset of my columns AND not having to type them all manually as in Jake's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply by using `group_by` and `summarize_each`. You then specify which variables you want to summarize, then replace the prefix in the names using `setNames`.

```
sample %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarize_each(funs(mean), var_hello, var_are) %>% 
   setNames(gsub("var_","computation_var_",colnames(.)))
```

Comment: thanks but that does not work. The problem is that  I have many variables, and even my subset list can be very large. So I dont want to type manually the mutate statement for each of them